# How to prevent a splash screen image from stretching

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am creating a game.
At the moment, for my splash screen, I use an image.
The problem is it stretches.
How do I prevent that?

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="hitesh.asimplegame.SplashScrean"
    android:background="@drawable/mulalo">
```

Comment: in which orientation you splash screen is? also your xml is incomplete. which view you using to display splash screen

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/mulalo"` Background images are meant to be stretched to fit their container size. Instead, you can use the `src` attribute of an ImageView.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Always use Imageview for displaying the image.

**Sample xml** for splash screen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/splash_bg"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace your image with **splash_bg**.

**NOTE :** As question with less information I am assuming that you are using only one image for the splash screen.

Comment: can you use RelativeLayout in .XML ?

Comment: yes its Layout and you can use in xml file. res > layout